# Type predicates not working in 'expanded' filter function

Tags: typescript, types

I have two classes:

```
class Dog {
  run() {
    console.log("RUN")
  }
}

class Fish {
  swim() {
    console.log("SWIM")
  }
}
```

I then make a `type` `union` through:

```
type Pet = Dog | Fish
```

I then use a `type predicate` to evaluate what is the superclass of `Pet` instances:

```
function isDog(pet: Pet): pet is Dog {
  return (pet as Dog).run !== undefined
}

function isFish(pet: Pet): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined
}
```

I then have an `array` of `Pet`s:

```
const zoo: Array<Pet> = [dog, dog, dog, fish, fish, fish]
```

I would like to `filter` the `array` having only `Fish` instances, I do:

```
const underwater: Array<Fish> = zoo.filter(isFish)
```

which works.

Why doesn't this work in the 'expanded' version of the `filter` `function`?

```
const underwater2: Array<Fish> = zoo.filter((p) => isFish(p))
```

Comment: Probably because you could do whatever you want inside the body of the arrow function. TypeScript doesn't do that much static analysis and so it just gives up and types the arrow function's return value as `unknown`.

Comment: Yes but isn't `zoo.filter(isFish)` automatically converted to `zoo.filter((p) => isFish(p))` by the compiler? If so, shouldn't it be able to understand it? @caTS

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't change that in the output. That's just regular JavaScript. You pass a function to the higher-order function `filter`. I don't really know why the compiler can't do the inference here. My first comment was just my interpretation of this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fifth case of open TypeScript issue [#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390). Though it might be possible to infer type-predicate return types for simple cases, the main problem seems to be that it would be a breaking change.

Currently, this code type checks:

```
const pets = zoo.filter(x => isFish(x));
// const pets: Pet[]

pets.push(new Dog()); // Allowed
```

However, if a type predicate would be inferred for the arrow function, it would fail:

```
const pets = zoo.filter((p): p is Fish => isFish(p));
// const pets: Fish[]

pets.push(new Dog()); // Type error
```

If necessary, you can specify the type predicate in the return type of the arrow function (i.e. `(p): p is Fish => isFish(p)`):

```
const underwater2: Array<Fish> = zoo.filter((p): p is Fish => isFish(p))
// const underwater2: Fish[]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNaAnArgOwAoBKVDTaYePCeEAUwDoQkCAiAJQFUA5VosgL5ohaUJBgAxAJYQAFqUwQA7lIC2xBeUrVajZojYBlAOoBJALJ9BwtGgAuATwAOdaAAU6d6AF44SaAA+0NJytgBm+MB2UlTQMggGLnYAXO6eRKlJcTAJmlieOFh40ARZkH6IRAy4xQCE3r74ACZ0YVJ4dE02aBF4UTHFMiGypZ6pHnYZ0FkywTLy6Jj5doXFo17lw1XKatD1jXgtbR1dIvReAF7w8KkAglhYYA4APBMAfD7QANoAurbaEC8zToWCUYDsILuDyez2GH18V3gDDaIAhWAIQ3m-AA9NjyNAAHoAfn+VEB0GBoPBIIATFDHi84Z9EcipKiQQRSlMnNk5nIfB9MXIuTi8eRibZFhQyV4kjAEddWez0QAPAXZYYEFVEIgAbjIuPxErIcoYThwwo6SgqxD10ENtxAzCUnW6UoBss88ugLJRaM5Tm5vOG6qFI0DeoNYswxswpvNlro1oStt19rxABVnK4QVh4FgbEA)